# Android setup activity with multiple "steps"

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I will explain what I want to achieve by this image:

[image]

When someone starts the app for the first time, setup activity will open and I want it to have multiple steps. I guess creating activity for each part of the setup is not the best solution. I would prefer if the activity would just transform to the part 2 without any animation or with a sliding animation and I want it to only change the setup part by pressing the buttons. What's the best / easiest way to achieve this? Thanks for any answers.

Comment: The best way would be to use `Fragments`. You can read more about them here - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Each step is a Fragment. To disable the swipe gesture subclass `ViewPager` and override `OnTouchEvent`

Comment: Why not simply use multiple fragments? I don't see any need of ViewPager here.

Comment: With a ViewPager you can easily implement the swipe between fragments function.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the best / easiest way to achieve this?

Use an existing library for this. Depending on the role of this UI, [ProductTour](https://github.com/matrixxun/ProductTour) might be appropriate, and if not, [one of the wizard libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/131) probably is.